# Is RPC a blanket term for all types of client server communications where a method on server is executed?

Tags: api, rest, http, grpc, rpc

I am trying to understand what is RPC. None of the articles clearly mention what is RPC. Does REST API calls, SOAP based calls or any other way of client server communication can be called as RPC? Or is it something different all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call

> In distributed computing, a remote procedure call (RPC) is when a computer program causes a procedure (subroutine) to execute in a different address space (commonly on another computer on a shared network), which is coded as if it were a normal (local) procedure call, without the programmer explicitly coding the details for the remote interaction.

The key is: `coded as if it were a normal (local) procedure call`.

So as long as there is a library or object that wraps and abstracts how the client communicates with the server, any protocol (SOAP) or underlying architectural style (REST), could be considered to implement RPCs.